# How to prove the existence of partitions of unity for smooth manifolds with boundary?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I have tried looking through various books and websites and could not find a proof of the existence of partitions of unity for smooth manifolds with boundary. I would like a proof or a reference to one.

Comment: Just repeat the proof for manifolds without boundary.

Comment: Is the proof go exactly the same? Aren't there any difference in the construction of the functions?

Comment: No difference, just try it and see if you get stuck at any point of the proof.

Comment: where exactly do we use the condition that a manifold is a manifold without boundary

Comment: When dealing with manifolds without boundary, we use $\textbf{regular coordinate balls}$. While handling manifolds with boundary, we use $\textbf{regular coordinate balls}$ or $\textbf{regular coordinate half balls}$. This might be the only difference between the proofs.

Answer (score 1):

The following is in German, if you can read it:

https://people.math.ethz.ch/~blatter/Analysis_14.pdf

The first page of chapter 14 is 223. Scroll down to pp. 255–261. There a partition of unity is constructed for domains $B\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ having a smooth boundary. Maybe you can translate the setup to your situation.